# Using Winding2 font in Azure web services

Tags: azure, gdi+, azure-web-roles

I have a service that uses Winding2 font to draw an image.  When I deploy it to Azure the characters are still drawn but just not in the correct font.  I think they are getting converted to Arial.  My question is, can I uses fonts like Windings2 on Azure web service instance?  How could I possibly know what other fonts are not supported.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just need to install the font using a script in start up task.
You can refer to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879738/azure-unable-to-start-cloud-service-running-vbs-startup-task/17879976#17879976)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I think I am running into exactly the same issue as the post you pointed to.  I adjusted this script to run in my environment and it works great connecting through RDP but when I try running it on the start up of the instance it just keep cycling.

Comment: Ok so I did figured this out, but I could not get vbs working I believe due to the permissions.  I had to create PowerShell script that installed my font and wrap it in cmd batch script that set powershell permissions before running font installation script.  Here is an excellent resource about writing startup scripts for Azure http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2011/02/07/azure-startup-tasks-and-powershell-lessons-learned.aspx.